# renderInContext: not rendering CALayer with transform applied?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-animation, calayer

Here is the code below:  Not sure what I'm doing wrong, here. It used to work when I was rendering the layer from a NIB file. I tried to change it by creating the view programmatically. Now it renders the layer but with no tranform applied.

```
- (NSBitmapImageRep*)getCurrentFrame
{
  CGContextRef    bitmapContext = NULL;
  CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace;
  int bitmapByteCount;
  int bitmapBytesPerRow;

  int pixelsHigh = (int)[fixedWidthStringView bounds].size.height;
  int pixelsWide = (int)[fixedWidthStringView bounds].size.width;

  bitmapBytesPerRow   = (pixelsWide * 4);
  bitmapByteCount     = (bitmapBytesPerRow * pixelsHigh);

  colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateWithName(kCGColorSpaceGenericRGB);

  bitmapContext = CGBitmapContextCreate (NULL,
                                       pixelsWide,
                                       pixelsHigh,
                                       8,
                                       bitmapBytesPerRow,
                                       colorSpace,
                                       kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);
  if (bitmapContext== NULL)
  {
        NSLog(@"Failed to create bitmapContext.");
        return nil;
  }

  CGColorSpaceRelease( colorSpace );


  [CATransaction setDisableActions:YES];
  fixedWidthStringView.layer.transform = CATransform3DScale(fixedWidthStringView.layer.transform, .5, 1, 1);
  [CATransaction commit];

  [fixedWidthStringView.layer renderInContext:bitmapContext];

  CGImageRef img = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(bitmapContext);
  NSBitmapImageRep *bitmap = [[NSBitmapImageRep alloc] initWithCGImage:img];
  CFRelease(img);

  return bitmap;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it myself. It turns out that this works as long as I add my NSView to another NSView and render the container.